# Regular Expression to replace "ABC42" by "Douglas" but leave ABC421 or ABC4244 intact

Tags: c#, regex

Well the title says it all ...

I have a file containing different flavors of the same string followed by different integers. Let's say I have ABC42 a couple of times, a few ABC422 and one ABC4244.

I want to replace "ABC42" by "Douglas" and keep the ABS422 and ABC4244 intact in the text.

I'm using the .Net Regular Expression parser.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a sample input? Is ABC42 that you want to replace a full word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use word boundaries (the `\b` metacharacter) to match the intended text exactly. Your pattern would be: `\bABC42\b`

```
string input = " Let's say I have ABC42 a couple of times, a few ABC422 and one ABC4244.";
string pattern = @"\bABC42\b";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "Douglas");
```

EDIT: in response to the comment asking whether this would work for "zzABC42_"...

It won't work in that case since the entire point of using `\b` is to match a word boundary. Since the pattern surrounds "ABC42" with `\b`, it matches the *whole word*. To match "zzABC42_" we can't use word boundaries anymore.

Instead, we need to *partially match* it and come up with a new criteria. Let's assume this criteria is *partially match "ABC42" as long as no other digits follow "42"*. I can drop the `\b` and use a negative look-ahead to prevent extra digits from being matched. This would resemble the following pattern: `ABC42(?!\d)`

```
string input = "Hello zzABC42_, ABC422 and ABC4244.";
string pattern = @"ABC42(?!\d)";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "Douglas");
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmad ... works great. Will it work if my ABC42 is not preceded or followed by a space like in "zzABC42_" ? If I want to replace it with "Douglas" and leave "kkABC4244#" intact will it work?

Comment: @Basbrun I've edited my post to respond to your comment. Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow man ... you'r fast! Thanks a lot for your help! I'll use these look-ahead, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code provided that `ABC42` is a word on its own (regex below matches based on word boundaries).

```
String input = "ABC42 a couple of times, a few ABC422 and one ABC4244 ABC42.";
String pattern = @"\bABC42\b";

String output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "Douglas");
```